# How to find by what means a software has been installed on linux

Tags: linux, software-installation, command-history

I have plenty of softwares installed on my Linux machine (RHEL) and some were installed with yum, 
some other by downloading a rpm and executed it from gnome file manager. I also have few softwares archives (zip or tar) I just unzipped in the /opt directory.

My question is: is it possible to know by which method I installed e.g the chrome browser which is located in /opt/google/ folder?

The answer can be different by Linux distro, but I am more interested for these distros: RHEL, CentOS, Fedora (sorted by importance).

The answer is enough for me if I can know: it was installed by yum, rpm or zip.

I checked the `history` (for both my own user and for `root`) but there is not traces there anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rpm -qa --last` is an easy way to find out when certain software was installed from RPM.

`rpm -qf /path/to/some/software` is pretty reliable to determine if the software was installed from RPM and which RPM (unless that is a symbolic link).

If it wasn't installed by RPM the software came to your system in "some other way".

Whether of not the RPM package came through a yum repository, or not: `yum info <rpm-name>` displays from which repository the RPM package is available. If the yum repository is now disabled or the RPM package was installed manually yum will list:  `Repo: installed`.